# Changing Field Name Value in ViewModel

Tags: json, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

Is there any way to change the FieldName Value for a property in a Viewmodel? I would like to use the standard naming convention for the property, but have the viewmodel return something else. This is important, because I have a json request that requires the properties to be in lowercase.

I have tried using both XMLAttributes, and DataMembers, but neither of those soultions worked. Those came from the following questions.

[Serialize .Net object to json, controlled using xml attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686817/serialize-net-object-to-json-controlled-using-xml-attributes)

[JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

So, to reiterate, I need something like this

```
 public string Start { get; set; }
```

to show up as

```
 viewmodel.start
```

instead of

```
viewmodel.Start
```

when I am passing my viewmodel to the callback inside the getJson request

Answer (score -1):

What about adding an extra property to your model?

```
public string start {get {return Start;}}
```