# How to specify a name to which object will be serialized by WebApi?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, asp.net-web-api

My web api is returning a set of objects which are differ from the Domain object. Forexample, I my domain has an Employee class but I don't want to expose all the members of the Employee class in my api so I created another class called EmployeeApiModel.

Now my WebApi is returning a List of EmployeeApiModel but I want to be able to specify the name to which it should serialize to. That is instead of `<EmployeeApiModel>` tag in the xml, I want to get `<Employee>` but without changing the fact that the underlying class which is being serialized is EmployeeApiModel.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your API supports both json and xml?

Comment: What does t mean "I want to be able to specify the name to which it should serialize to"?

Comment: Yes, both Xml and Json.. Actually that is handled by the WebApi itself. But I should be able to specify something which works for both XML and Json

Comment: @CuongLe I edited the question for more clarity. The Tags were missing earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, Web Api support both json and xml based on content negotiation mechanism, Json is the default format, if you want to receive xml, just put on header:

> Accept: application/xml

To understand more content negotiation, access [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/25/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-1.aspx)

Since you want your api support both json and xml, you should use DataContract and DataMember Attribute for serialization for your model: EmployeeApiModel, something like:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Employee")]
public class EmployeeApiModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name2")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

See more on this [blog-post](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the output of your serialized XML by using various Attribute tags.

```
[XmlRoot("Employee")]
Public class EmployeeApiModel
{
    [XmlElement("fname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

this will produce XML like:

```
<Employee>
    <fname>John</fname>
     <LastName >Smith</LastName >
    <age>24</age>  
</RootElementsName>
```

You can read more about the various XML modifiers here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e123c76w.

If you want to use existing XML modifiers for JSON, check out this post: [Serialize .Net object to json, controlled using xml attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686817/serialize-net-object-to-json-controlled-using-xml-attributes)

Comment: This does not seem to work with the Web Api. I added XmlRoot but still get the same ApiModel as the root.