# How to cause a JSON property to be converted to XML as an attribute of an xml-element

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

Using Newtonsoft's .Net Library to convert JSON to XML, is there a way to convert a specific JSON element to an XML attribute?

For example, taking the following JSON:

```
{
    "array": {
        "item": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        "length": 3
    }
}
```

and converting it to:

```
<array length="3">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</array>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you prefix the attributes with @ and put them at the top of the object? It says in the docs:

> Attributes are prefixed with an @ and should be at the start of the
>   object.

looks like: `"@length": "3",` for a definition of an attribute called 'length'

Alternatively you could deserialize your JSON into an object and then reserializing it as Xml:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="array")]
class JsonToXmlTranslationObject {

     [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
     public int[] item { get; set; }

     [XmlAttribute]
     public int length { get; set; }
}
```

Then use your Json serializer to deserialize into it, and then use an Xml serializer to serialize the `JsonToXmlTranslationObject` into your XML.

Comment: How do you decorate a class with a tag that has the @ included?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686817/serialize-net-object-to-json-controlled-using-xml-attributes