# Converting JSON to XML using JSON.NET: convert an element to an attribute only if not null

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

We're using JSON.NET to convert a tiered object into JSON, then from there into XML.

> We're aware of the arguments against doing this, but there are several
>   arguments in favor of it, and we've tried a lot of things to get here.

An issue we're running into is that occasionally a property will have a null value.  When the [property is getting converted to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293965/how-to-cause-a-json-property-to-be-converted-to-xml-as-an-attribute-of-an-xml-el), that's fine, but when it's an attribute, we get a `NullReferenceException` thrown.  Our preference would be to have nulls get converted to empty strings, however leaving them out entirely would be acceptable.

How can we handle this?

Comment: Where are you getting the NRE?

Comment: See below; it was on `string` properties.  A little getter alteration put a sturdy, but case-specific patch on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of analysis turned up that all the `NullReferenceException`s we were getting were on `string` properties.  I put the following in the **getter** to return `string.Empty` instead of `null` if indeed the string hadn't been initialized.  *This is not an elegant solution, however it works for our situation.*

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@Code")]
    public string ProductCode
    {
        get { return _productCode == null ? string.Empty : _productCode ; }
        set { _productCode = value.Trim(); }
    }
```